# blinking while navigation from one page to another in jquerymobile and phonegap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, navigation

I am new to jquerymobile and doing a project in which i have 4 pages like A,B,C,D...In all the pages i have two tab bar or navigation bar.Page A is static , In page B i am showing a listview updated dynamically from server.In page C i have some images to be displayed updating from server.In page D i have to display a map location for that i am using google maps.he problem is while testing this app in my android phone 2.2..i am getting lot of flickering and blinking while navigation from one page to another.not getting in a proper alignment. i have used the solution given in stackflow of using of

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

but of no use.please help me.Any help will be appreciated.if anyone wants to check my code i can provide them.

thanks

Comment: I see the same on similar Android devices :( and have seen comments from jQuery Mobile acknowledging the flicker. RC3 boasts "page transition smoothness, and page rendering speed" so perhaps there's hope with the new RC.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem testing an app on Android 2.2. Try testing your app on a device with a higher version of Android and you should notice quite a difference. This is because Android 2.2 was quite slow. When version 2.3 came out there was a huge step in performance. If you do want to keep the app looking good for older Android users, you can consider trying to turn the animations off or disabling shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay gals, I think I have a big-time answer to this really bad problem!

On my device, the blinking occurs only if the page I'm transitioning to has some kind of animation in its pagebeforeshow or pageshow handler. For example, I have a page with a listview which sometimes fades a special warning into view. Whenever that warning is shown, the page transition will blink when going to that page. When it is not shown, there is no blink.

And the best thing: there is a reasonable workaround!

It helps to postpone animations by a few seconds. On my Nexus S with Android 4.0.3 (which is lousier than lousy in terms of jQueryMobile page transitions), 800ms is enough delay to prevent the blinking, and 400ms is too short. Even at 800ms, it doesn't feel like a strange pause in page loading from a user perspective.

Another thing that helps is not to set focus to inputs too soon. This too seems to confuse the browser about which page it's animating, and thus causes it to jump back and forth between the old and new page. Again, 800ms is enough delay to appease the animation engine and it's likely still to appear instantaneous.

There also seems to be more risk of flickering if the page you're transitioning to has both a pagebeforeshow and a pageshow event handler. If only one of these is attached, no blinking. The transition is still not always very smooth, but at least there are no ugly flashbacks to the page you thought you just left.